# Phase portrait of dx/dt = sin(y), dy/dt = cos(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I was going over Strogatz's Nonlinear Dynamics & Chaos in an attempt to study for my upcoming midterm, when I came across the following question:
6.3.5: Find and classify the fixed points of the system $\frac{dx}{dt} = \sin(y), \frac{dy}{dt} = \cos(x)$.
I found the critical points, which were $(x, y) = ((k - \frac{1}{2})\pi, k\pi)$.
I figured out the Jacobian, which was
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \cos(k\pi)\\
-\sin(k\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}) & b
\end{pmatrix},
which is equivalent to the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & (-1)^k\\
(-1)^k & 0
\end{pmatrix},

Which yields the characteristic equation $\lambda^2 - (-1)^k(-1)^k = 0$.
If k is even, this means $\lambda^2 = 1$. If k is odd, it still means $\lambda^2 = 1$. Either result means $\lambda = \pm1$, so every point $((k - \frac{1}{2})\pi, k\pi)$ is a saddle point. However, when I actually graph this differential system, I end up getting the following phase portrait:

[image]

Which shows several other fixed points besides $((k - \frac{1}{2})\pi, k\pi)$ . In fact, fixed points exist at all points of the form $((k_1 - \frac{1}{2})\pi, k_2\pi)$. Furthermore, not all these fixed points are saddles points as I hoped, some seem to be centers. I'm guessing this is because I should have had 2 separate k values earlier on, and whenever $k_1$ is odd but $k_2$ is even, or vice versa, we obtain center fixed points since the eigenvalues are purely imaginary. Can someone please confirm if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Yes, the equations $0=\sin(y)$ and $0=\cos(x)$ are not coupled, their solutions independent, so every pair of solutions is a fixed point.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see, thanks.